# How to have one label for multiple select boxes?

Tags: html

I have on this check in form:

```
<label>Check in date </label>
<select id="day">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
</select> 
<select id="month">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
</select> 
<select id="year">
  <option value="1">2012</option>
  <option value="2">2013</option>
</select>
```

As you can see, the user will choose the month, the day and the year on different select boxes, however, only one label should exist for all three.

What would be the proper way to do this with HTML ?

Update:
I'm concerned with the accessibility hit that we may have on developing something like the code above. I mean, a blind user should be able to listen each label in order to fill this form...

Comment: Don't see a problem with what you have. Any reason why you would expect otherwise?

Comment: its working fine.IS there anything specific that you want..? http://jsfiddle.net/B2MrM/

Comment: A workaround can be to create multiple diuplicate `label` elements for each `select` and use CSS to hide the duplicates so only the first one is displayed. Label for screenreaders should still be able to read the duplicates as the screenreaders read the source code not the output our eyes see.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot associate a `label` element with more than one control. This is described in the [definition of `label`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.9.1).

You could give each `select` element its own label.

A better approach is to have a single text input field for a date. Then there is no problem with `label`. It means more work, since you have to parse the data server-side, and you should also parse it client-side (for checks, so that the user can immediately be informed of problems). But it is better usability (surely it is faster to type in a date than to use three clumsy dropdowns) and better accessibility. You need to decide on a date format and clearly tell the user what the expected format is.

Comment: Questionable usability advice IMO, and not really a solution to the problem, just a way around it.

Answer (score 14):

The problem with using one label for all three input boxes is that an non-sighted user is not going to know which of three boxes the focus is in because the same text will be read out in each case. There's a number of approaches possible. Maybe the safest is to have a label for each box, but hide those labels off to the left side of the viewport. Another possibility which ought to work, but I haven't tested would be this:

```
<fieldset>
    <legend>Check in date</legend>
    <select id="day" aria-label="day">
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
      <option value="3">3</option>
      <option value="4">4</option>
    </select> 
    <select id="month" aria-label="month">
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
      <option value="3">3</option>
      <option value="4">4</option>
    </select> 
    <select id="year" aria-label="year">
      <option value="1">2012</option>
      <option value="2">2013</option>
    </select>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: Didn't know about aria-label property. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Simply having aria-label may be enough for this scenario, here.

Answer (score 8):

Following with the answer from @Alohci, you can also use `aria-labelledby` and reverse the naming reference (*which I think is a bit closer to the convention you were looking for*):

```
<label id="date">Check in date</label>
<select aria-labelledby="date">
    <!-- ... -->
</select> 
<select aria-labelledby="date">
    <!-- ... -->
</select> 
<select aria-labelledby="date">
    <!-- ... -->
</select>
```

Also note, as per [the W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/states_and_properties#aria-labelledby) on `labelled-by`:

> If the label text is visible on screen, authors **SHOULD** use `aria-labelledby` and **SHOULD NOT** use `aria-label`. Use `aria-label` only if the interface is such that it is not possible to have a visible label on the screen. User agents give precedence to `aria-labelledby` over `aria-label` when computing the accessible name property.

Answer (score 1):

There is no proper way; a label refers to one element. Just point it to the first one.

```
<label for="day">Check in date </label>
```

You could also use a specifically-styled `<fieldset>` if you like semantics, but I think that's a bit overkill. An `<input type="date">` is probably the best option here, as it is one element that can be pointed to by your `<label>`, is more semantic, and can be somewhat friendlier if you implement a good date picker to go along with it.

If you want to stick with the `<select>`s, try giving each one a `title` attribute for accessibility.

Answer (score 1):

Trying to improve @Bracketworks answer:

```
<label id="date">Check in date</label>
<label for="day" id="label_day">Day</label>
<select id="day" aria-labelledby="date label_day">
    <!-- ... -->
</select> 
<label for="month" id="label_month">Month</label>
<select id="month" aria-labelledby="date label_month">
    <!-- ... -->
</select> 
<label for="year" id="label_year">Year</label>
<select id="year" aria-labelledby="date label_year">
    <!-- ... -->
</select>
```

See example 1 of MDN's "[Using the aria-labelledby attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Accessibility/ARIA/ARIA_Techniques/Using_the_aria-labelledby_attribute)".

Answer (score 0):

HTML5's [`input type="date"`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.date.html) might be useful too, particularly if you're using month/day/year select boxes as a way to limit date selection possibilities. This input element supports `min` and `max` date attributes, so you can apply your limitations. It's not supported by older browsers, but I've seen smart cookies use [jQueryUI's datepicker](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/) as a shim (by using [capabilities detection](http://modernizr.com/) to determine `type="date"` support, then loading in and invoking the datepicker only if it isn't supported natively).

Answer (score 0):

from: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label

"...you can nest the 'input' (or 'select' in this case) directly inside the 'label', in which case the for and id attributes are not needed because the association is implicit"

```html
<label>Check in date 
    <select id="day">
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
      <option value="3">3</option>
      <option value="4">4</option>
    </select> 
    <select id="month">
     <option value="1">1</option>
     <option value="2">2</option>
     <option value="3">3</option>
     <option value="4">4</option>
    </select> 
    <select id="year">
     <option value="1">2012</option>
     <option value="2">2013</option>
    </select> 
 </label>
```