# why label inside label for two element not working

Tags: html, label

In my code, label "Two" for second input set in label "One" for first input, but when click to label "Two", then first input not activated.

HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="inp_one">
<input type="checkbox" id="inp_two">
<div>
  <label for="inp_one">
    <h1>One</h1>
    <label for="inp_two">
      <h1>Two</h1>
    </label>
  </label>
</div>
```

My code: https://jsfiddle.net/5x6ytk3g/

i want when click label "Two" then activate for both input.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to have one label for multiple select boxes?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12164617/how-to-have-one-label-for-multiple-select-boxes)

Comment: I think my problem is not the same. I want to answer why why two nested labels cannot work correctly. And you can access the example above to try to experience what I'm saying !!

In fact, when I asked this question, I was doing an essay on a website that was only built with html + css, although the answer below was not as expected of me, but I think it worked For those who have ever asked the problem you mentioned is duplicate.

Comment: I ended up here because I was curious about labels inside labels. The spec very specifically mentions nested labels are invalid content for labels: `and no descendant label elements` https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/forms.html#the-label-element

Comment: The answer I wanted was answered here by Andy Ford.
[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38172221/why-label-inside-label-for-two-element-not-working#comment101709896_38172221)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you need to use JavaScript:

```
document.getElementById("inp_two").onchange = function(){

    document.getElementById("inp_one").checked = this.checked;

};
```

https://jsfiddle.net/5x6ytk3g/1/

I tried it. Good luck VN!